# Make cell.imageviews follow reordering of a cell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

So I’m trying to make image views of cells follow the drag and drop of that cell, I'm using [this control: BVReorderTableView](https://github.com/bvogelzang/BVReorderTableView) to enable reordering cells without editing mode.
(I've already emailed the developer about my issue)

Texts inside the cells of my table view have no problem with the reordering, but the image views of these cells do not follow.

I’m willing to try any other controls you suggest for reordering cells, or do it myself (but I’m a beginner).

The code:

```
  - (id)saveObjectAndInsertBlankRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  id object = [self.ArrayofFiveFriends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  [self.ArrayofFiveFriends replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@""];
  return object;
  }

 - (void)moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)toIndexPath {
  id object = [self.ArrayofFiveFriends objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
[self.ArrayofFiveFriends removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
[self.ArrayofFiveFriends insertObject:object atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
 }

 - (void)finishReorderingWithObject:(id)object atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; {
[self.ArrayofFiveFriends replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:object];
}
```

Comment: can you give us the code where you setup the cell ? (probably the cellForRowAtIndexpath method)

Comment: Sure, here it is

http://pastebin.com/E7hMagJF

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems quite simple. In your code, you did this :

```
NSString *friendID = [self.ArrayofFriendsID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture", friendID]];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
cell.imageView.image = image;
```

You can see that your cell image is based on the data stored in self.ArrayofFriendsID. However when you reorder your cells you only update self.ArrayOfFiveFriends. (cf : the code in your post). This is why your images won't follow.

Comment: My problem is the way BVReorderTableView works I can only update one list, the ArrayofFiveFriends (which contains the name of these friends).

Can I return multiple values with the functions of BVReorderTableView of my original post? (this way I could update the names and the pictures), or do I need to manually change the class of BVReorderTable to handle multiple parameters?

The main problem is how to handle the cells of mytableview in those functions. I'll try another control I found for that like [this one](https://github.com/jamztang/JTGestureBasedTableViewDemo)

Comment: Same issue with JTGestureBasedTableView

Comment: Instead of having two arrays, can you try to create an array of dictionary elements ?

The dictionaries would look like this : 
    @{ @"friendID" : friendID, @"friendObject" : friendObject }

Comment: I'll try that, I need to know more about dictionaries (I tried to set IDs as keys and images as objects, and didn't work).
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I did it !

I used this [tutorial](http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/reordering-a-uitableviewcell-from-any-touch-point/)

I works great images follow the text (In fact you just set editing mode by default and hide every editing elements + some customizations)

Thanks Kujey for trying to help me !